# Can you use MERGE with ON CREATE SET on a property with an existence constraint?

Tags: neo4j, constraints, cypher

As only the enterprise edition of neo4j supports existence constraints, I can't test this myself.

As an example, let's say I have an existence constraint on a relationship property, :Likes(createDate), usually used where one :Person likes another person.

Obviously a create call like this will fail because of the existence constraint:

```
MATCH (a:Person{id:1}), (b:Person{id:2})
CREATE (a)-[:Likes]->(b)
```

I would have to create the relationship with the createDate property to comply with the constraint.

But what if the relationship already exists? I want to do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person{id:1}), (b:Person{id:2})
MERGE (a)-[v:Likes]->(b)
ON CREATE SET v.createDate = timestamp()
```

I fear that this wouldn't be allowed, but I don't know whether the existence constraint is checked at the time of the MERGE, or after the ON CREATE. Seems like this would be a fairly standard use case, and I'd like to know if the enterprise edition allows this without problems or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Neo4j checks the state of the node after `ON CREATE` has been called and it is complete:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE CONSTRAINT ON ()-[r:Likes]-() ASSERT exists(r.createDate);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Property existence constraints added: 1
212 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (a:Person {uid: 1}), (b:Person {uid: 2});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 2
Properties set: 2
Labels added: 2
63 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (a:Person {uid: 1}), (b:Person {uid: 2}) MERGE (a)-[r:Likes]->(b);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Relationships created: 1
41 ms
ConstraintViolationException: Relationship 1398105 with type "Likes" must have the property "createDate" due to a constraint
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (a:Person {uid: 1}), (b:Person {uid: 2}) MERGE (a)-[r:Likes]->(b) ON CREATE SET r.createDate = timestamp();
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Relationships created: 1
Properties set: 1
43 ms
```

I'm using Neo4j Enterprise Edition 3.0.3.